# how to split text in textbox and assign text before + operator to integer i and text after + operator to integer j

Tags: c#, wpf

creating calculator using only one textbox for accepting data and for displaying data using c# wpf

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        int i,j;
        double sum = 0.0;
        Char sign;

      public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btn0_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString(0);
        }

        private void btn1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString(1);
        }
private void btn2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString(2);
        }

        private void btn3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString(3);
        }

        private void btn4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString(4);
        }

        private void btn5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString(5);
        }

        private void btn6_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString(6);
        }

        private void btn7_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString(7);
        }

        private void btn8_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString(8);
        }

        private void btn9_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString(9);
        }

private void btn_eql_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            j = System.Convert.ToInt32(tb1.Text);

            switch (sign)
            {
                case 'p': sum = i + j;
                    tb1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(sum);
                    break;
                case 's': sum = i - j;
                    tb1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(sum);
                    break;
                case 'm': sum = i * j;
                    tb1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(sum);
                    break;
                case 'd': sum = System.Convert.ToDouble(i) / System.Convert.ToDouble(j);
                    tb1.Text = System.Convert.ToString(sum);
                    break;
            }

        }
private void btnp_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString("+");
        }

        private void btns_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString("-");
        }

        private void btnm_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString("*");
        }

        private void btnd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString("/");
        }

        private void btn_exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }

        private void btn_dot_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString(".");
        }

        private void btn_ob_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString("(");
        }

        private void btn_cb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text + System.Convert.ToString(")");
        }

        private void btnc_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = String.Empty;
        }

        private void btnb_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            tb1.Text = tb1.Text.Substring(0, tb1.Text.Length - 1);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string s = "3+57";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches( s, @"(\d+)\+(\d+)", RegexOptions.None );
int i = int.Parse( matches[0].Groups[1].Value );
int j = int.Parse( matches[0].Groups[2].Value );
int sum = i + j;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] str=tb1.Text.Split('+');
int i=int.Parse(str[0]);
int j=int.Parse(str[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex` to split text and store the values.

```
string[] MyNum = Regex.Split(tb1.Text, "+");
int i = (int)(str[0]);
int j = (int)(str[1]);
```